# What happens if `on_runtime_upgrade` during migration fails?

Tags: parachain, migration

In parachain context, imagine we have declared a migration within `type Executvie` where we want to migrate some state from pallet A to pallet B in `on_runtime_upgrade`. In the new wasm the pallet A gets deleted and pallet B gets added.

What if `on_runtime_upgrade` fails somehow in the middle way? We could have some incomplete or corrupted state for both pallet A and B, right? If this migration is related to block authoring (e.g. session/collator settings), is it possible that the parachain gets stuck?

Is there a way to prevent that besides try-runtime and testing on the testnet?

Answer (score 2):

No, `on_runtime_upgrade` must not fail. If it fails, you are in big troubles, which most of the time means that your chain is fucked.

As you already said, make sure to use `try-runtime` and test nets to test the upgrade.

Comment: Thank you  :) would it be possible to keep the block production unstoppable even when such a thing happens? I believe one of the biggest concerns is the chain gets stuck after an inappropriate runtime-upgrade or migration.

E.g. divide the runtime-upgrade into 2 parts and only apply the new wasm when the migration succeeds. Is that feasible? Or like perform try-runtime as an on-chain check beforehand and refuses to upgrade when something unexpected happens

Comment: No you can not run try-runtime on chain. There is also not really anything that you can do to bring back the block production. For standalone blockchains there is some issue on what could be done: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/7558